# How to make links within a QML `Text` element show pointing hand mouse cursor when hovering?

Tags: html, css, qt, hyperlink, qml

In a web browser, when you hover the mouse over a link it changes to the pointing hand. I want to achieve the same in QML.

Here is a QML `Text` element containing a block of text, using HTML markup, that includes a couple of links:

```
Text { id: bodyMessage
   anchors.fill: parent
   textFormat: Text.RichText
   wrapMode: Text.WordWrap

   text:
      '<p>' + qsTr('Here is my first paragraph.') + '</p>' +
      '<p>' + qsTr('My second paragraph contains the <a href="link1">first link</a>.') + '</p>' +
      '<p>' + qsTr('My third paragraph contains the <a href="link2">second link</a> and that is it.') + '</p>'

   onLinkActivated:
      (link) =>
      console.log('Link activated to: `' + link + '`')
}
```

The problem is that the mouse cursor does not change to a pointing hand when it is over either link.

I tried a child `MouseArea` as follows:

```
   MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      hoverEnabled: true

      onPositionChanged:
         (mouse) =>
         cursorShape = bodyMessage.linkAt(mouse.x, mouse.y) ? Qt.PointingHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
   }
```

This does get the mouse cursor to change as desired, but it blocks mouse signals to `Text`, so `onLinkActivated` no longer works.

To solve that new problem, I added the following to `MouseArea`:

```
                onClicked:
                    (mouse) =>
                    {
                        let link = bodyMessage.linkAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
                        if (link.length > 0)
                            console.log('Link activated to: `' + link + '`')
                    }
```

While this does work, it renders `Text.linkActivated` obsolete, which seems to me the wrong approach and the code looks bloated to me.

Comment: Aside from **@stephen-quan**'s answer, which is the best approach, you can use the `acceptedButtons` property of `MouseArea` and set it to `Qt.NoButton`.  To prevent stealing of the clicked signal. [[ref](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#acceptedButtons-prop)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding `HoverHandler` to your `Text`:

```
Text {
    HoverHandler {
        enabled: parent.hoveredLink
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
    }
}
```

If we wish to control the color of the link when it's hovered, not hovered, we use a conditional on hoveredLink:

```
Text {
    text: qsTr('<style>a:link{color:%1;}</style>My second paragraph contains the <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"> StackOverflow link</a>.').arg(hoveredLink ? "purple" : "red")
}
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    title: "HoverHandler Demo"
    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 10

        Frame { Label { text: "Initial Solution"  } }

        LinkText {
            text: `
<p>${qsTr('Here is my first paragraph.')}</p>
<p>${qsTr('My second paragraph contains the <a href="link1">first link</a>.')}</p>
<p>${qsTr('My third paragraph contains the <a href="link2">second link</a> and that is it.')}</p>

`
        }

        Frame { Label { text: "Revised Solution" } }

        LinkText { text: qsTr('Here is my first paragraph.') }
        LinkText { text: qsTr('<style>a:link{color:%1;}</style>My second paragraph contains the <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"> StackOverflow link</a>.').arg(hoveredLink ? "purple" : "red") }
        LinkText { text: qsTr('<style>a:link{color:%1;}</style>My third paragraph contains the <a href="https://www.google.com" style="{link:red}">Google link</a> and that is it.').arg(hoveredLink ? "purple" : "red") }
    }
}

// LinkText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Text {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap

    HoverHandler {
        enabled: parent.hoveredLink
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
    }
        
    onLinkActivated: {
        console.log('Link activated to: `' + link + '`');
        Qt.openUrlExternally(link);
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-hoverhandler.html

Comment: I love this solution to the mouse pointer part of the question. Much more elegant and compact that a `MouseArea`.