QML: change link's background on hover in a TextArea
I have a TextArea component with richtext content that also includes links. When I hover a link I would like to change its background.
I know that I can use css like syntax to change styling in text documents by adding for instance a style tag to it's content and also that the pseudo class :hover doesn't work in QML.
I also tried the approach of adding a rectangle to the textarea and tried to find a way to get it behind the text. I tried using the z-property but this didn't work. Also I wasn't able to exactly determine the position of the hovered link to position the rectangle accordingly.
So my question is how can I add a hover effect to a link that changes its background?
Here my (still incomplete) code so far:
import QtQuick 6.5
import QtQuick.Controls 6.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.5

Rectangle {
    color: "#555"
    anchors.fill: parent

    RowLayout
    {
        TextArea {
            Rectangle {
                id: linkHoverBackground
                width: 100
                height: 30
                color: "#050"
                z: 0
            }

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            z: 1
            text: "<style type=\"text/css\">a { color: #090; } a:hover { color: #900; }</style>" +
                "<h3>TextArea Element:</h3>" +
                "Hier ein <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Testlink</a><br>" +
                "Und hier noch ein <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Testlink</a> mit Text dahinter"
            color: "#ddd"
            textFormat: TextEdit.RichText

            //styleSheet: "a { color: #090; }" -> error, prop doesnt exist

            MouseArea
            {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton // Don't eat the mouse clicks
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                onPositionChanged: function(e)
                {
                    console.log(e.x, e.y)
                    linkHoverBackground.x = e.x
                    linkHoverBackground.y = e.y
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I may be wrong, but I don't think this is doable, at least not directly from QML. In order to set the correct the geometry of the "background rectangle" you'd need to access the underlying QTextDocument so that you can eventually retrieve the bounding rect of the specific text fragment of the link.

Possibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78030298/how-to-make-links-within-a-qml-text-element-show-pointing-hand-mouse-cursor-wh

The TextArea.hoveredLink property is set/unset whenever your mouse glides over the link. However, this is set for any link being hovered on. To manipulate the style of one hover link vs another, I found it necessary to split the text over multiple TextAreas. Also, I found it best to use string interpolation whereby both the linkColor and linkBackgroundColor can be fed to the TextArea.
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        TextAreaLink {
            text: `<h3>TextArea Element:</h3>`
        }
        TextAreaLink {
            text: `${style}Hier ein <a href="https://www.google.com">Testlink</a>`
        }
        TextAreaLink {
            text: `${style}Und hier noch ein <a href="https://www.google.com">Testlink</a> mit Text dahinter`
        }
    }
}

// TextAreaLink.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
TextArea {
    property string style: `<style type="text/css">a { color:${linkColor}; background-color:${linkBackgroundColor}; }</style>`
    property string linkColor: hoveredLink ? "yellow" : "green"
    property string linkBackgroundColor: hoveredLink ? "blue" : "transparent"
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    color: "#ddd"
    
    HoverHandler {
        enabled: parent.hoveredLink
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
    }

    onLinkActivated:
        (link) =>
        console.log('Link activated to: `' + link + '`')
}

You can Try it Online!
Here's another solution that supports:

h3 ... h3 headings
p ... p paragraph blocks

The headings are rendered using a single Label.
The paragraph blocks are rendered using a Flow+Repeater+Label.
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    RichTextLabel {
        width: parent.width
text: `<h3>RichTextLabel Element:</h3>

<p>Hier ein <a href="https://www.google.com">Testlink</a></p>

<p>Und hier noch ein <a href="https://www.google.com">Testlink</a> mit Text
dahinter. Und hier noch ein <a href="https://www.google.com">Testlink</a> mit Text
dahinter. Und hier noch ein <a href="https://www.google.com">Testlink</a> mit Text
dahinter.</p>`
    }
}

// RichTextLabel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ColumnLayout {
    id: rta
    property string text
    Repeater {
        model: rta.text.match(/(<h\d+\>[^]*?<\/h\d+\>|<p\>[^]*?<.p\>)/g)
        ColumnLayout {
            id: outer
            property var _m: modelData.match(/(<h\d+\>[^]*?<\/h\d+\>)|<p\>([^]*?)<\/p\>/)
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Label {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                visible: _m[1]
                text: _m[1]
                textFormat: Text.RichText
            }
            Flow {
                id: flow
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                visible: _m[2]
                spacing: 6
                Repeater {
                    model: _m[2].match(/(<a.*?<\/a\>|[^\s]+)/g)
                    Label {
                        property color linkColor: hoveredLink ? "yellow" : "blue"
                        property color linkBackgroundColor : hoveredLink ? "blue" : "transparent"
                        text: `<style type="text/css">a { color:${linkColor}; background-color:${linkBackgroundColor}; }</style>` + modelData
                        textFormat: Text.RichText
                      onLinkActivated: {
                          console.log('Link activated to: `' + link + '`');
                          Qt.openUrlExternally(link);
                      }
                      HoverHandler {
                          enabled: parent.hoveredLink
                          cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

You can Try it Online!

Thank you that is already very close to what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I sometimes have the case that there are multiple links within one sentence as well but I guess I'll find a way to adjust this for that case

For the same sentence, I recommend using Flow. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-flow.html
